# A nil value is transformed to 0 instead of triggering a validation error. How can I prevent this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Model `Plan` has a `jsonb` column `:per_unit_quantities_configuration` . It is a hash with 3 keys/values pairs, `min`, `max` and `step`.

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :per_unit_quantities_configuration, :min, :max, :step, prefix: true
end
```

I have validations in place to prevent awkward configurations and/or infinite loops building an array of options based on those configuration settings.

First, I cast the values to from `string` to `float` `before_validation`

```
before_validation :cast_per_unit_quantities_config_values

  def cast_per_unit_quantities_config_values
    return unless per_unit_quantities_configuration_changed?

    self.per_unit_quantities_configuration_min = per_unit_quantities_configuration_min&.to_f
    self.per_unit_quantities_configuration_max = per_unit_quantities_configuration_max&.to_f
    self.per_unit_quantities_configuration_step = per_unit_quantities_configuration_step&.to_f
  end
```

And then I have each individual fields values' validations:

```
  validates :per_unit_quantities_configuration_min,
            numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }, allow_nil: false
            
  validates :per_unit_quantities_configuration_max,
            numericality: { greater_than: lambda { |p| p.per_unit_quantities_configuration_min } }
            
  validates :per_unit_quantities_configuration_max
            numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }, allow_nil: false
            
  validates :per_unit_quantities_configuration_step,
            numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, allow_nil: false
```

The problem I'm having is that when the user tries to send the form with the `min` field empty (`nil`), it is transformed to `0` which is a valid value for the field but is not appopiate since API users would receive no feedback that the change is being made.

What is converting the `nil` value to `0` ? And why is the `allow_nil: false` validation not triggered instead?

Answer (score 1):

> What is converting the `nil` value to `0`?

The call to `.to_f`:

```rb
nil.to_f
 => 0.0
```

If you're starting with an empty string instead of a `nil` then the safe navigation operator won't save you:

```rb
nil&.to_f
 => nil

""&.to_f
 => 0.0
```

> And why is the `allow_nil: false` validation not triggered instead?

You changed the value in a `before_validation` callback.  The validations will run against the new value.

You may want to remove the `before_validation`.  This way, you can use the Rails numericality validations to filter out any invalid values (`nil`, `""`, `"x"`, etc.).  If you still need to do something to the value before it gets stored in the database you may want to use an `after_validation` callback instead.

Comment: Thank you, but I get a `invalid value for Float(): ""` from the update action in the controller.

Comment: also, I put a byebug in the casting method, and I can confirm it stops at the byebug AFTER it goes through the update action (which explains the error above). How is that even possible?

Comment: The `to_f` will not be executed if the value is `nil` due to the safe navigation operator (`&.`) e.g. `nil&.to_f #=> nil`

Comment: @engineersmnky I removed the safe operator and the `invalid value for Float(): ""` error persists.

Comment: My comment was more for the Answer than your question. Your actual issue is you are passing an empty string (not `nil`). This will result in a similar `0` issue and also explains why safe navigation did nothing e.g. `""&.to_f #=> 0` . Maybe try adding `allow_blank: false` instead? or make sure you are passing `nil` or nothing at all for this attribute

Comment: @engineersmnky thank you, but the error persists with `allow_blank: false`

Comment: @engineersmnky - Ah, right.  I misread the `&.`.  `@pinkfloyd90` - Are you sure you're starting with a `nil`?  Could you share what the `params` look like?  Maybe you're starting with an empty string.

Comment: @cschroed the OP is absolutely starting with an empty string based on this `invalid value for Float(): ""` this error is raised from `Float("")`

Comment: I've updated my answer with one way to get around this by using `.present?` before casting to a float.

Comment: @cschroed i think checking `present?`  is not enough, since `'x'.to_f == 0.0`

Comment: I couldn't figure that one out so I left it as is. Not casting the value to prevent nil being transformed into 0 brought more problems than it fixed.